# Mac OS parent domain name

Tags: macos, dns

This question falls under "I don't even know what to Google".

I have a Mac OS workstation with a static IP and assigned domain name of `foo.example.com`. The machine is connected to the `example.com` network and using `example.com` DNS servers.

I'm expecting `ping bar` to have identical behavior to `ping bar.example.com` — that is, ***assume*** the `example.com` domain when no domain is specified.

That did happen correctly on this workstation in the past. However, I just moved to a new IP address on a new subnet and now `ping bar` says "unknown host" whereas `ping bar.example.com` still works normally.

What setting do I need to be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Search Domains**
System Prefs > Network > [specific connection] > Advanced... > DNS

[image]

From the System Help on that page...

> You can use Domain Name System (DNS) servers and search domains to
>   avoid typing the complete address of Internet domains you use
>   frequently.
>
> DNS is the way Internet domain names are located and translated into
>   Internet Protocol (IP) addresses.
>
> The search domains you enter in your Network preferences are
>   automatically appended to names you type in Internet apps.
>
> For example, if you specify the search domain apple.com, typing
>   “store” in your web browser takes you to store.apple.com. Or, if you
>   use campus.university.edu as a search domain, you can type “server1”
>   in the Connect To Server dialog in the Finder to connect to
>   server1.campus.university.edu.